# passing POST array to php function

Tags: php

Can i pass the entire POST array into a function and handle it within the function?

such as

```
PostInfo($_POST);


function PostInfo($_POST){
    $item1 = $_POST[0];
    $item2 = $_POST[1];
    $item3 = $_POST[2];
        //do something
return $result;

}
```

or is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Those are superglobal variable. You may see them in every functions, if register_global is on.

Comment: Please note that `register_globals` (not `register_global`) is not required to use `$HTTP_POST_VARS` (the non-superglobal and deprecated brother to `$_POST`)! See here: http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals

Comment: Right, that was my other guess as to it's use. Couldn't remember exactly, but I knew Aif was wrong. At any rate, `register_globals` is **bad**! Beyond that, it's deprecated. Don't use it!

Comment: Related: [PHP: $_GET and $_POST in functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1354691/367456)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. If you are going to name the local variable `$_POST` though, don't bother. `$_POST` is a 'superglobal', a global that doesn't require the `global` keyword to use it outside normal scope. Your above function would work without the parameter on it.

> **NOTE** You cannot use any superglobal (i.e. `$_POST`) as a function argument in PHP 5.4 or later. It will generate a Fatal error

Answer (score 9):

You can actually pass $_POST to any function which takes in an array.

```
function process(array $request)
{

}

process($_POST);
process($_GET);
```

Great for testing.

Comment: This is the preferred way to do it. It's called [dependency injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 2):

The [`$_POST`-array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is an array like every other array in PHP (besides being a so-called [*superglobal*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)), so you can pass it as a function parameter, pass it around and even change it (even though this might not be wise in most situations).

Regarding your code, I'd change it a bit to make it more clear:

```
PostInfo($_POST);

function PostInfo($postVars)
{
    $item1 = $postVars[0];
    $item2 = $postVars[1];
    $item3 = $postVars[2];
        //do something
    return $result;
}
```

This will visibly separate the function argument from the `$_POST` superglobal. Another option would be to simple remove the function argument and rely on the superglobal-abilities of `$_POST`:

```
PostInfo();

function PostInfo()
{
    $item1 = $_POST[0];
    $item2 = $_POST[1];
    $item3 = $_POST[2];
        //do something
    return $result;
}
```