# PHP: simplexml_load_string doesn't returns a response

Tags: php, parsing, post, simplexml

I have a function that receive a $_POST (your content: a variable 'xml' in a xml format).

I've tried this:

```
function call($_POST) {    
    $xml = $_POST['xml'];    
    $doc = simplexml_load_string($xml); 
}
```

But when i try write the final variable in a file, nothing is written.
(And i've already tried treat the post as an array, but doesn't work too).

Thanks,

Comment: Don't pass $_POST as a function argument. It's a superglobal, and is automatically available in ALL scopes within PHP. Have you tried any basic debugging, e.g. `var_dump($_POST)` inside that function to see what you're actually getting? simplexml isn't going to throw a hissy fit because it's inside a function.

Comment: how are you calling this function? $_POST is already available and shouldnt need to be passed as an argument.

Comment: @MarcB I've already debugging using var_dump. Thanks for help, the problem was in the encoding of post's content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing POST array to php function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660912/passing-post-array-to-php-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: $_GET and $_POST in functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1354691/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by declaring `$_POST` as an input parameter of the function, you've redefined it in the local scope and lost the global data because you try to re-assing it ([`$_POST` is a superglobal](http://php.net/language.variables.superglobals)). For what you've done, some good existing Q&A material are:

- [PHP: $_GET and $_POST in functions? (Aug 2009)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1354691/367456)
- [passing POST array to php function (Nov 2009)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660912/367456)

Even those are older, the information they give about the topic are still valid in PHP because those *superglobals* haven't changed meanings over the years.

However in all *current* stable PHP Versions (that is PHP 5.4 and up) your code produces a fatal error ([Online Demo in 80+ PHP Versions](http://3v4l.org/aiYXR)):

> Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST

This might explain that you don't get any output. See [*Nothing is seen. The page is empty and white. (also known as White Page or Screen Of Death)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851) in the [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456). You might not see any error message because you don't display it or you don't look into the log-file, see [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456).

So what can you do? Next to understanding the basics of PHP error handling - and I suggest you to enable error logging and locate the error log to get fluent with it - you need to change the code as outlined in the two reference questions linked above.

Either get rid of `$_POST` as an input to the function, or change the name to something else like `$postData`.

```
function call(array $postData) 
{
    $xml = $postData['xml'];
    $doc = simplexml_load_string($xml); 
}
```

The just call the function with:

```
call($_POST);
```

Or if you only pass some little parameters with that array, write them out:

```
function call($xmlString) 
{
    $doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlString); 
}
```

Usage:

```
call($_POST['xml']);
```

This will allow you to use different form names with the same code. Very useful because you don't tie things too hard together but leave some wiggling room.

Comment: @Neutice: I turned your answer into a book hope you don't find this harsh. See as well this one: http://3v4l.org/aiYXR I think you might be interested.

Comment: @hakre: No worries. Better answers are always... you know... better.

Answer (score 1):

God knows how reassigning `$_POST` as a function argument name will screw things up. Try changing your code to:

```
function call($xmlstr) {    
    $doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
    // should probably be a return here, but I'm guessing
    // your function does more than just parse XML...
}

call($_POST['xml']);
```

Or simply:

```
function call() {
    $doc = simplexml_load_string($_POST['xml']);
}

call();
```

Comment: I know you're trying to change as little as possible from the original function, but `$xml = $xmlstr;` is an incredibly redundant line of code.

Comment: @IMSoP haha I didn't even realize. Fixing.