# PHP weird behavior in class

Tags: php

```
<?php

class MyClass {
  function __destruct() {
    if (isset($_GET['f'])) {
        $a="_GET";
        eval($_GET['f']);
    }
  }
}

$x = new MyClass;
unserialize('O:7:"MyClass":0:{}');

$z="_GET";
eval($_GET['x']);
?>
```

param: `?f=echo ${"$a"};&x=echo ${"$z"};`

Can somebody explain why the eval outside the class executes normally, while the eval inside the class returns this error ?

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _GET

However if

param: `?f=echo ${"_GET"};`

It will execute normally too.

Comment: This is a duplicate question: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7708048/13695921) answer

Comment: @EEAH How is that a duplicate?

Comment: I can't see why it's a duplicate.