# How to execute a function with an isset under an if statement in PHP

Tags: php

I am making a loan calculator and I want to run some calculations that are being posted from a form using the POST method. The code is not executing when I run it. Where am I am missing it?

I have run the code without the function and it seems to be working well, but the moment I put it in a function its not running.

```php
function loancal()
{
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $principal = $_POST['principal'];
    $intrstRate = $_POST['intrest'];
    $tenure = $_POST['tenure'];
    $result = ($principal * $intrstRate * $tenure) ;
    echo $result;
  } else {
    echo '00.00';
  }
}
```

This is the line that is calling the function after it has been submitted:

```php
<h1 class="title is-2"> $<?php loancal(); ?></h1>
```

I am expecting the out to change from $00.00 to for example a calculated result, but the output is still the same $00.00

This is the form (excerpt).

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="principal">
  <input type="text" name="intrest">
  <input type="date">
  <input type="text" name="tenure">
  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
  <button type="reset" >Clear</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your form itself also? Without seeing the form, I would try NOT using the submit field in isset but instead a different field in the form and see if that works for you.

Comment: $_GET, $_POST is the superglobal variables, they can be accessed anywhere on the file and methods, best practice to validate the posted data and pass them as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar i am new to php, why is it the $_POST superglobal not working in a function?

Comment: @Raymond refer to this this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354691/php-get-and-post-in-functions

Comment: @Raymond the superglobal issue isn't what you are experiencing. RakeshJakhar is referring to best practices, not problem solving your issue.

Comment: Need form CODE not an image of the form.

Comment: You should show the _code_ of your form, not its screenshot.

Comment: @AbraCadaver the code is there, the screenshot was requested by someone.

Comment: @Raymond I apologize, I meant post the form code not the screen shot of the form.

Comment: FORM CODE dude, like `<form...><input name=....>blah blah</form>` etc...

Comment: @AbraCadaver i have added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my very first answer is your issue, you need to give your submit button a name.

```
<button name="submit" class="button is-rounded is-primary" type="submit">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: This was the issue.i fixed this and i worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: It doesn't really "need" a value with the `isset` check.

Comment: @AbraCadaver that was a habit I picked up from another language that caused issues so I just learned to put it there as a habit now I guess.

Comment: @imvain2 It would be good to explain to OP _why_ it should be so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the code to execute:

```
<?php

function loancalc() {
$result = '0.00';
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] )){
// inspecting submitted values so that... 
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
      $bool[$key] = ctype_print( $value );
    }
// ... if proven valid, then make assignments               
    if ( $bool['principal'] && $bool['interest'] && $bool['tenure'] ) {
// array destructuring available since PHP 7.1
      [$principal, $interestRate,$tenure] = 
      [$_POST['principal'],
      $_POST['interest'],
      $_POST['tenure']];
      $result = $principal * $interestRate * $tenure;
     } // inner if
 } // if POSTed
    echo number_format( $result,2,'.',',' ); // default English representation
} // end func
?>

  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
<style>
#submit {
  background: #000;
  color: lime;
}

#clear {
  background: #000;
  color: cyan;
}

input {
  background: #ffffee;
  color: #303;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32pt;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  color: #f0c;
}
 </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>$&nbsp;
      <?php loancal(); ?>
    </h1>

    <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="principal" id="principal">
      <input type="text" name="intrest" id="intrest">
      <input type="date">
      <input type="text" name="tenure" id="principal">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Calculate</button>
      <button type="reset" id="clear">Clear</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The form values will only be properly submitted if they possess `name`  attributes.  `Id` attributes are optional and handy for front-end code manipulation.

Important point: Be sure to treat user submitted data as suspect, i.e. possibly tainted.  In this example, a simple check makes sure that the the user input values only contain printable characters.

(Related demo of PHP code [here](https://3v4l.org/p2SSu).)

Refinements:

gave **$result** default value and eliminated an if-else clause

formatted the number with `number_format()` to make the number more user-friendly.

added some styling for fun :)